# find the expected error value

Tags: probability

I want to calculate the expected error value in an n-bit number with the probability of bit flip $P_{bit}$. I will explain the calculation for a simple case in which two least significant bits might have error while other bits are error-free. In this case the errors will be in the range [-3, +3]. I have a simple solution for the case when the number of erroneous bits are small. I iterate over all the possible errors and find their probability of occurrence and then calculate the average error. However, this solution is not scalable for the cases when the erroneous bits are larger (e.g. 20 bits or more). I am wondering if there is any simpler solution to calculate the expected error value in this case.

**EDIT**

The n-bit number is unknown and the probability of bit flip is equal among all the bits. Also the probability of each error pattern is the same.

Comment: are the bits independent? How is it that you can have $-3 $ errors? are your bits $0,1$  or $-1,1$? If errors add up then you might calculate $\Bbb{E} [errors] = n P_{bit}$

Comment: you could have 11 in the two least significant bits and then you have two bit flip in the least significant bits which convert 11 to 00. Therefore, the relative error will be -3.

Comment: For one bit error, it is quite simple to find the expected error value. I feel there should be a pattern for higher number of bit error as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your $n$-bit number is fixed and only your bit flips are random and independent. The expected total error over all bits is the sum of the expected error contributed by each bit. The latter should be easy to work out.

[After the question edit...]

The above reasoning remains valid for each possible $n$-bit string. Now if each $n$-bit string is equally likely, then each bit has an equal probability of being $0$ or $1$. Thus if it is flipped, the error that bit contributes would be the same magnitude but positive or negative with the same probability. Hence the expected contribution is zero. Note that the bit flip probability is irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: This "easy" part is exactly the problem. How could you work out the contribution of each bit? Each bit flip affect the value differently. Suppose we have bit flip in the second least significant bit. If the original value is one then the erroneous value will be three (+2 absolute value). But if the original value is two then the erroneous value will be 0 (-2 absolute value).

Comment: @AmirYazdanbakhsh: But **as I clearly stated in my assumption** you already know the original value. If you don't, then your question has **missing information**.

Comment: Thanks again for the solution. The problem here is the scalability of the solution. I want to find the expected error value. Suppose you have 32 bits and you can have any number of bit flips. How are you going to calculate the error for all the possible cases? It requires 2^32 (original values) x 2^32 (error pattern) search.

Comment: I still believe there should be a systematic way to find the expected value without iterating over all the possible cases.

Comment: @AmirYazdanbakhsh: You obviously have not specified your question properly. **Nowhere** in your original question did you say you have an **unknown** $n$-bit string. Furthermore, you still do not specify how often I should expect to see each of those strings. Without that your question has an unknown answer.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the question. But I thought when we talk about the expected value it implies that we are averaging among different cases.

Comment: @AmirYazdanbakhsh: "Unknown" is not precise. As I said in my comment: `you still do not specify how often I should expect to see each of those strings.` You already mentioned the bit flip probability in your first line, which is understood to mean that every bit has that probability of being changed. But you did not answer my question. Expectation does **not** "average among cases". The expected value of playing the lottery is not the average between losing and winning.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining precisely and thanks for help. Let's assume that these strings are equally likely to happen.

Comment: @AmirYazdanbakhsh: Great! I've edited my answer. See if it makes sense.

Comment: @AmirYazdanbakhsh: (You should still edit your question to include the last bit of information that you gave in your last comment.)